# Regain control of ViewPart after restarting eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I am building a Papyrus editor extension plugin(e4) in eclipse, it's a simple ViewPart listening to the editor selections and displaying data. My problem is that after restarting eclipse my view is still visible (I don't really mind that), but the listeners are disposed.
The plugin is initialized from a popup menu. So is there a way to get this orphaned view on startup so I can re-init the controls.

What I tried is implementing IStartup, but the getActivePage() method throws an exception.

```
public class StartupHandler implements IStartup {

@Override
public void earlyStartup() {
    IWorkbenchPage page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
    IViewReference[] viewReferences = page.getViewReferences();
    for (IViewReference iViewReference : viewReferences) {
        //  identify view
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that you can specify `restorable="false"` on the org.eclipse.ui.views definition so that the view is not restored on restart. Also note that org.eclipse.ui.xxx code is not e4, it is 3.x compatability mode.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I did see the restoreable option but, even if I set it to false the view is still there after a restart.